# Is running multiple databases on login going to make my Mac really slow?

Tags: macos, database, launchctl

Sometime ago, I installed Postgres, and the Launch agent that causes it to run when I log in.  Just now, I did the same thing for Mongo.  I was just about to do it for Couch.  I don't remember if I ever did it for MySQL, but I probably did.  Mongo and Couch are just 'when I have time to look into it' sort of things, but I don't want to have to remember to start them when I do.  I have a 2.4 Ghz processor and 8 GB ram.  Is this sort of behavior going to significantly impact my computer's performance?  Should I be scrambling to uninstall all but the database I'm currently using, or can I install all the things and run them all the time?

Thanks

Comment: It probably won't slow it down significantly, but **why don't you just give it a try**? It's hard to precisely answer this question because the answer's always going to be, "Yes it'll probably slow down the machine", but no one can know for sure.

Comment: I guess the reason I'm asking is because (a), I don't want to have to remember to start them to use them, and (b), things tend to get lost once I install them.  I want to know, general case, if this is the kind of thing I can just do and forget about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is running more programs at the same  time going to slow down my machine?  Yes.

Will it be noticeable? If you have a fast hard drive and a small database, probably not.

Should you uninstall them? Well no, just don't make them start up when you log in. What does it matter if it's not running at start up if  you only occasionally want to work on it. Just run the command to start them. If you're other solution is to reinstall your databases every time you want to play with them, you're in for a lot more hurt than if you just start them manually when you want to use them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that I can just stop and start them, but barring that, I want to know what kind of an impact just running them will have.  I'd really like to just 'install and forget.'

Comment: Well just running without any operations being done on them will be ok considering you have quite a lot of memory and seemingly do not have gigabytes of data in your database. I don't think it will slow you down noticeably when it is idling.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably accept your answer, but want to see what else comes in.